# If polynomial is zero, its coefficients are zero

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

On reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, Chapter 4, I tried to prove the following theorem:

**Theorem**. Suppose $a_{0},\dots,a_{m}\in\mathbb{F}$.
If $a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots+a_{m}z^{m}=0$
for every $z\in\mathbb{F}$, then $a_{0}=\cdots=a_{m}=0$.

Note that, following the convention of the book, $\mathbb{F}$ is either
$\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}.$

This is my attempt:

*Proof*. Suppose $a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots+a_{m}z^{m}=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{F}$
($\dagger$). Let $f\left(z\right)=a_{0}+a_{1}z+\cdots+a_{m}z^{m}$.
Then $f\left(z\right)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{F}$, that is, $f=0$.
Hence, by definition, $\deg f=-\infty$. Suppose there is $j\in\left[0..m\right]$
such that $a_{m}\neq0$. We can choose the maximum of such $j$, let
it be $m'\in\left[0..m\right]$. Then $\deg f=m'$. Since $m'\in\left[0..m\right]$,
$\deg f\geq0$, which contradicts $\deg f=-\infty$. Therefore, $a_{0}=\cdots=a_{m}=0$.

But it is quite different from the proof in the book and seems simpler.
[image: relevant portion of the book]

I suspect there might be a circular argument in my proof, but I could not find a clue. Question: Is this proof correct? If not, what is wrong with this proof?

Comment: A polynomial (not the polynomial function) is defined to be zero if all it's coefficients vanish. Correspondingly the degree is defined to be $-\infty$ provided all the coefficients vanish. So essentially your argument boils down to ''all the coefficients vanish because all the coefficients vanish ".

Comment: Stripping it down to its essentials, your proof reads like the following. "We have $P$. Suppose $\neg P$ holds. This is a contradiction." This isn't a valid method of proof.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I checked the book and this author equates functions with polynomials functions, which works for $0$ characteristic fields.

Comment: Note that this is wrong in a finite field. In an infinite field , we can use that a polynomial with degree $n>0$ has at most $n$ roots , but it must have infinite many roots. Hence the polynomial must be constant and therefore identically $0$.

Comment: Needs a definition of the notion polynomial.

Comment: Avoid using pictures for large portions of your question. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: See this question: [Two questions about a proof that "if a polynomial is the zero function, all of its components are zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169442/two-questions-about-a-proof-that-if-a-polynomial-is-the-zero-function-all-of-i?rq=1).

Comment: @GitGud interesting, I didn't realize the author defined it this ("reversed") way

Comment: @K.defaoite It was me who included the screenshot.

Comment: @Peter That's not precise enough, I don't think. You can take an infinite field with non-zero characteristic. Example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58425/55235).

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the feedback.  I have (therefore) deleted my answer.  I assumed that comments following the posting had resolved the issue of whether the OP's work was valid, so that it only remained to furnish a proof of the underlying assertion.  Also, I have never studied Field Theory so, I am clearly out of my depth.  Again, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @GitGud It is correct. The map from the polynomial ring to the ring of functions is injective if and only if field is infinite. Characteristic zero of course is sufficient, but is not necessary. See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304888/742). Argument works for positive characteristic, as long as the field is infinite. Peter is correct.